# SQLAlchemy WHERE IN single value (raw SQL)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble with SQLAlchemy when doing a raw SQL which checks against multiple values.

```
my_sess.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `key`='rating' AND uid IN :uids",
        params=dict(uids=some_list)
    ).fetchall()
```

There are 2 scenarios for this query, one that works and one that doesn't. If `some_list = [1]`, it throws me an SQL error that I have a syntax error near `)`. But if `some_list = [1, 2]`, the query executes successfully.

Any reason why this would happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, SQL parameters only ever deal with *scalar* values. You'll have to generate the SQL here; if you need raw SQL, use:

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `key`='rating' AND uid IN ({})".format(
    ', '.join([':i{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(some_list))]))

my_sess.execute(
        statement, 
        params={'i{}'.format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(some_list)})
    ).fetchall()
```

e.g. generate enough parameters to hold all values in `some_list` with string formatting, then  generate matching parameters to fill them.

Better still would be to use a [`literal_column()` object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) to do all the generating for you:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import literal_column

uid_in = literal_column('uid').in_(some_list)
statement = "SELECT * FROM able WHERE `key`='rating' AND {}".format(uid_in)

my_sess.execute(
        statement, 
        params={'uid_{}'.format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(some_list)})
    ).fetchall()
```

but then you perhaps could just generate the whole statement using the `sqlalchemy.sql.expression module, as this would make supporting multiple database dialects much easier.

Moreover, the `uid_in` object already holds references to the right values for the bind parameters; instead of turning it into a string as we do with the `str.format()` action above, SQLAlchemy would have the actual object plus the associated parameters and you would no longer have to generate the `params` dictionary *either*.

The following should work:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, literal_column, select

tbl = table('table')
key_clause = literal_column('key') == 'rating'
uid_clause = literal_column('uid').in_(some_list)
my_sess.execute(select('*', key_clause & uid_clause, [tbl]))
```

where the [`sqlalchemy.sql.select()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) takes a column spec (here hard-coded to `*`), a where clause (generated from the two clauses with `&` to generate a SQL `AND` clause) and a list of selectables; here your one [`sqlalchemy.sql.table()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.table) value.

Quick demo:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import table, literal_column, select
>>> some_list = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> tbl = table('table')
>>> key_clause = literal_column('key') == 'rating'
>>> uid_clause = literal_column('uid').in_(some_list)
>>> print select('*', key_clause & uid_clause, [tbl])
SELECT * 
FROM "table" 
WHERE key = :key_1 AND uid IN (:uid_1, :uid_2)
```

but the actual object tree generated from all this contains the actual values for the bind parameters too, so `my_sess.execute()` can access these directly.

Comment: While I understand what your answer does, and printing the `statement` variable produces a valid SQL, I'm getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'` when calling the `execute` method.

Comment: @EduardLuca: Ah, I never use `session.execute()` and it indeed only supports named parameters. Will update.

Comment: @EduardLuca: You really should look into generating the SQL using SQLAlchemy's core functionality, however. It can handle `in` generation too, I bet.

Comment: Thanks for that. 2 things: I don't think I can use its core functionality to generate the queries, because I don't have models (mapping classes), I just want to build a quick app. Also, you have 2 syntax errors in your updated answer, the `[` and `{` brackets in `join` and `params` don't close up, and seeing how that kind of syntax is completely new to me, I'm not sure where I should close them.

Comment: @EduardLuca: you don't *need* mapping classes to generate SQL with the core functionality. It's nice to have, but not required.

Comment: @EduardLuca: I fixed the dict comprehension, my apologies.

Comment: I found another issue with the code which I think I fixed, so I'm going to go ahead and edit the answer if that's OK with you. Got it to run now, so thanks. Will definitely look into the SQL generation thing.

Comment: @EduardLuca: I added a sample select generator, and corrected the rest of the code too.

Comment: Awesome! That really helps.