# In clause query on Python (pymysql and mysql.connector)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I want to use this query:

```
select x from y where z in ("a", "b", "c")
```

I have pymysql and mysql.connector for MySQL with Python.

This works with pymysql:

```
args = ["a", "b", "c"]
db = cur.execute('select x from y where z in %s',(tuple(args),))
```

But it doesn't work with mysql.connector. It gives me error like *'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'*.

pymysql has a great solution, but I couldn't realize that on mysql.connector. Can you help me please?

Comment: Also [SQLAlchemy WHERE IN single value (raw SQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21481541). The answer to the question I linked you to uses `?` as the placeholder, simply use `%s` as the SQL parameter placeholder instead. The second link in this comment generates `:i0`, etc. named placeholders; more complex and probably not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
db = cur.execute('select x from y where z in (%s,%s,%s)',tuple(args))
```