# Python - Filtering SQL query based on dates

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, psycopg2

I am trying to build a SQL query that will filter based on system date (Query for all sales done in the last 7 days):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

con = p.connect(db_details)
cur = con.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql("""select store_name,count(*) from sales 
     where created_at between datetime.datetime.now() - (datetime.today() - timedelta(7))""",con=con)
```

I get an error

```
psycopg2.NotSupportedError: cross-database references are not implemented: datetime.datetime.now
```

Comment: you never defined what `datetime` was in the sql

Comment: Your `between` is invalid too, you don't have a `and ...` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing Python syntax into your SQL query. SQL is parsed and executed by the database, not by Python, and the database knows nothing about `datetime.datetime.now()` or `datetime.date()` or `timedelta()`! The specific error you see is caused by your Python code being interpreted as SQL instead and *as SQL*, `datetime.datetime.now` references the `now` column of the `datetime` table in the `datetime` database, which is a cross-database reference, and `psycopg2` doesn't support queries that involve multiple databases.

Instead, use *SQL parameters* to pass in values from Python to the database. Use placeholders in the SQL to show the database driver where the values should go:

```
params = {
    # all rows after this timestamp, 7 days ago relative to 'now'
    'earliest': datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7),
    # if you must have a date *only* (no time component), use
    # 'earliest': datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7),
}
df = pd.read_sql("""
     select store_name,count(*) from sales 
     where created_at >= %(latest)s""", params=params, con=con)
```

This uses placeholders as defined by the [`psycopg2` parameters documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters), where `%(latest)s` refers to the `latest` key in the `params` dictionary. `datetime.datetime()` instances are directly supported by the driver.

Note that I also fixed your *7 days ago* expression, *and* replaced your `BETWEEN` syntax with `>=`; without a second date you are not querying for values between two dates, so use `>=` to limit the column to dates at or after the given date.

Comment: thanks for your reply, just encountered a error that returns


AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today' for the Params query. Could you please assist on that.. Thanks..

Comment: @KevinNash: please read my answer carefully, I corrected the expression to calculate the `earliest` value.

Comment: @KevinNash: you are not using the `datetime` module correctly, at any rate. I also added a `datetime.date.today()` variant in a commented-out line.

Comment: thanks. If I may extend this one step further. I tried to do the same for Store Name that is a string (has values like store_1, store_2).

I created a new param

params_2 = {'name' : 'Store 1', 'Store 2'} and passed this in the SQL.. It throws an error saying invalid syntax. could you please throw some light on this. Tnx..

Comment: @KevinNash: that's because `{'name' : 'Store 1', 'Store 2'} ` is not valid Python syntax. You'd have to use a *single* value for parameters, so either `{'name' : 'Store 1'} ` or `{'name': 'Store 2'}`, but not both. If you need to match multiple, you'd have to [generate multiple parameters for an `IN (....)` test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481541/sqlalchemy-where-in-single-value-raw-sql) (careful, that is aimed at MySQL). For psycopg2 code, also look at the [`psycopg2.sql` module](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) to help generate the parameters.

Comment: Could I please request you to help modify the above code you provided with a sample of how I could use multiple params in the same SQL. I referred to the same links you shared but keep getting invalid syntax. Tnx

Comment: @KevinNash: please ask a new question with your attempts; comments are there just to help clarify answers to the question posted, really.

Answer (score 2):

`datetime.datetime.now()` is not a proper SQL syntax, and thus cannot be executed by `read_sql()`. I suggest either using the correct SQL syntax that computes current time, or creating variables for each `datetime.datetime.now()` and `datetime.today() - timedelta(7)` and replacing them in your string.

edit: Do not follow the second suggestion. See comments below by Martijn Pieters.

Comment: No, do *not* just generate SQL with values in a string. Use sql parameters; those make sure you get correctly escaped and quoted, and give the database a chance to re-use query plans even when the values change.

Comment: See [Pandas read\_sql with parameters](//stackoverflow.com/q/24408557), since `psycopg2` is used you'd use `%s` for positional parameters, and `%(name)s` for named parameters.

Comment: Note that there are several other issues with the query, as shown. The Python code to calculate a datetime 7 days ago is incorrect and doesn't use the `datetime` module reference for `timedelta`, *and* the `BETWEEN` operator is missing the `AND ...` part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove that Python code inside your SQL, compute your dates in python and then use the strftime function to convert them to strings.

Then you'll be able to use them in your SQL query.

Comment: There is zero need to convert the Python `datetime` objects to strings, as `psycopg2` supports those natively. Provided they use SQL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not necessarily need any params or computations in Python. Just use the corresponding SQL statement which should look like this:

```
select store_name,count(*)
from sales 
where created_at >= now()::date - 7
group by store_name
```

Edit: I also added a `group by` which I think is missing.